# CT8G4DFS824A compatible with CT8G4DFS832A?

Tags: memory, compatibility

I currently have installed "Crucial 8GB DDR4-2400 UDIMM" (CT8G4DFS824A) in my PC but I want to install a second one.

Is there any negative effect if I would install a "Crucial 8GB DDR4-3200 UDIMM" (CT8G4DFS832A) instead of the same Chip? (Beside, that it will only run at the speed of the old one)

I have checked:

-The CT8G4DFS832A is completely comatible with my Mainboard

The only differences I could find are the following:

- __________________CT8G4DFS824A___CT8G4DFS832A
- Speed:____________DDR4-2400_______DDR4-3200
- CAS Latency:______17_______________22
- Extended Timings:___CL = 17__________22-22-22
- PC-Speed:_________PC4-19200_______PC4-25600

CT8G4DFS824A: https://www.crucial.de/memory/ddr4/ct8g4dfs824a

CT8G4DFS832A: https://www.crucial.de/memory/ddr4/ct8g4dfs832a

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try their configurator, see if it appears in the list - https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer

Comment: It should work, but the faster ram will be clocked down to match the slower ram. You will get more memory, but it will not be faster.

Comment: Ok Thanks to both of you. It appears in the List you sent @Tetsujin. I Think I will just go for it