# How much RAM to add t i3-6100 processor to fasten speed?

Tags: memory, ssd, performance, speed, processing

I am having desktop with i3-6100 processor with 4GB Ram with 1TB HDD. But it slows down while video editing in Filmora, slows down while opening heavy PPT or Chrome Browser.

1. Can adding 4GB more Ram and adding SSD will resolve issue?
2. How much more RAM should I add with existing 4GB?
   Should I add 4GB more or 8Gb more RAM?
3. Does is support 4GB RAM in one slot and 8GB RAM in another slot?

Comment: Have you tried googling these questions?

Comment: Use the Crucial configurator to see how much RAM your machine can take. We don't have enough information to answer your question… plus, blindly adding RAM won't fix the effect your slow old HD has on your system. https://www.crucial.com/store/systemscanner [US store, it may redirect to one local to you]

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer but I'd already vtc as 'not enough info'.

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree it might not make a huge difference but at 4GB it's likely the swap / paging file is in use. Increasing the RAM will reduce the reliance on the HDD. Both components should be upgraded to get the best performance increase.

Comment: @joshkrz - sure, Windows paging is hideously aggressive… but we don't yet know if the OP even has a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an extra RAM will almost certainly speed your system up. Opening large files, video editing and Chrome use a lot of RAM. 16GB is pretty standard today and 8GB is the minimum I'd go for.

It's usually not recommended to mix and match RAM sticks but I have known it to work before. Just make sure you get the same speed of RAM, similar timings (CL) and the same brand at least.

An SSD will make a huge difference when opening files and video editing.