# RAM upgrade for the Quanta 3603

Tags: laptop, memory

I have a laptop with a Quanta 3603 motherboard and I want to upgrade the RAM from 3gb to 8gb.
Just to confirm, I'm suppose to buy SODIMM DDR2 2x4gb RAM sticks right? or is there some sort of specific replacement I need to get? or will any SODIMM DDR2 2x4gb RAM sticks work?
And currently I have 3gb of RAM: DDR2, SODIMM, I think 1gb and 2gb, because there are 2 slots
https://gyazo.com/dc44dbce7360ae4b91523465d0a22ec5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Comment: Not really, I was just wondering if for my motherboard I needed to look up something specific like you're suggesting or just get any SODIMM DDR2 2x4gb RAM  sticks

Comment: Then 'no'. That's not enough information to decide what you need. See the linked question. It's there precisely for users who don't know how to find the exact info required to choose RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you check out the [Crucial Advisor tool](https://www.crucial.com/store/advisor).  It scans your computer and tells you what you have and what you can upgrade to.  You are limited by the motherboard's maximum amount of RAM.

If you have a 32-bit OS, you will need to reinstall with a 64-bit OS to take advantage of more than 4 GB of space. Most computers are 64-bit these days, though.

You particular motherboard came up when I searched for it and [someone appears to have answered the question here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/RAM-upgrade-for-dv5-MB-Quanta-3603/td-p/7000259).