# I have no idea in ram/random access memory is it okay to upgrade 667 mhz to 1333 mhz?

Tags: memory

I have 2x2gb ram ddr3 667 mhz on my pc, can i upgrade my ram up to 2x4gb ram ddr3 1333 mhz? I am planning to buy new pair, and i am newbie in pc building/pc parts. I hope someone will help me. On HWinFO program it says 666.7 MHz (DDR3-1333/PC3-10600), what does it mean? Does it mean that i'm using half of the speed of my ram?

Comment: See [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Comment: No, DDR stands for Double Date Rate, which means it can transfer at both the rising and falling edge of a clock cycle, effectively doubling its throuhput. So 667Mhz is effectively 1333Mhz.

Comment: i see, thanks for the info, well appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some program like HWiNFO to get the exact specs of the computer parts you already have, and then check online what memory types are supported by your CPU and motherboard. There are several possible combinations, and we can't guess what's inside you computer.

If a memory type is supported by the motherboard but not the CPU, it will still work, but at a lower speed (the max speed supported by the CPU).

Desktop computers will generally accept anything you throw at them within the supported specs, but have in mind that laptops are much pickier about memory upgrades and sometimes accept only specific memory brands and models.

Also, consider replacing your HDD with an SSD as well if you don't already have one. It's the most important upgrade for you.

Comment: i see, thanks for the info.

Comment: On HWinFO program it says 666.7 MHz (DDR3-1333/PC3-10600), what does it mean? I'm using half of the speed of ram?