# Can I install higher frequency ram than what my motherboard supports?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I have a laptop HP 14-am519tu.. online websites shows that it supports DDR4 RAM upto 2333 mhz.
I have bought 2666 mhz ram online https://www.amazon.in/dp/B08C56KXQJ/ref=cm_sw_r_apan_glt_fabc_1TD433YK8STGF54HGMJP

As fas as I have searched online, it says 2666mhz will work in 2333mhz motherboard. Will it really work guys..?? I am buying 2 sticks of 8gb to have 16gb ram in my laptop.

Will I face any problem if I use 2666 mhz ram in 2333mhz motherboard..??

Comment: Why guess, then ask if it will work? Why not just buy the right stuff in the first place? See [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Comment: Likely yes, but you won't be getting 2666MHz speed. So unless you're getting some kind of really good price break, there probably isn't much point.