# Can I upgrade my PC RAM with 1 8GB module?

Tags: memory

I have an old HP Proliant N40L; specs [here](https://www.hp.com/nz-en/pdf/HP_ProLiant_MicroServer_tcm_194_1127013.pdf) (PDF). I'd like to increase the RAM to 8GB. Now I only have 2GB in one slot.

According to the specs I can install 2GB (1x2GB) Standard or 4GB (1x4GB)/8GB Maximum, using PC3-10600E DDR3 Unbuffered (UDIMM) ECC memory, operating at max. 800MHz

Is it possible to install 1x8GB with a higher speed? something like [this](https://www.esseshop.it/patriot-ddr3-sl-8gb-1333mhz-udimm-1x8gb-p-170087.html?utm_source=GoogleBase1&utm_medium=BaseFeed1&utm_campaign=products&gclid=CjwKCAjwkvWKBhB4EiwA-GHjFu3m0RYZRW5S2x-55M6PiikYtmzjI9yH_KriomfYXLNUKCoHt4pb9xoClsoQAvD_BwE)?

Comment: See [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Comment: Very unlikely. The system doesn't support RAM modules >4GB.

Comment: Thansk for the feedback. Only Kingston give me a hint 4GB DDR3 1333MHz ECC Unbuffered DIMM. If I understand correctly I can install 2x4gb of ram at maximum

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the specs, no, you probably can't. It says right on page 3 of the spec sheet that the maximum supported RAM size is 4GB per slot. There is a slim chance that it *might* work anyways, since sometimes mainboards are capable of operating out of spec (and it's possible that there weren't any 8GB sticks when this manual was printed looking at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory#DRAM) list), but I really wouldn't count on it.

Comment: ok thanks. I found on amazon this ram. https://www.amazon.it/dp/B009BRZHSS/?coliid=I2BEJNSN2FOA5M&colid=3M9UPSSPF9Z23&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it&th=1 what if I instead live the 2gb standard ones and add only this 4gb? It seems in the comments of amazon that it works on my microserver.

Comment: So, wait, let me get this straight: You have two 2GB modules in the microserver right now, right? And you want to add a 4GB module? Then you'll have to remove one of the 2GB modules since the board only has two slots.

Comment: may I keep the 2gb as it is and add a 4gb once? at the end I'll have 6gb. Otherways  Ican buy 2x4g and replace the old one plus a second one. 1 x slot

Comment: Yes, this will probably work. There is a very small chance that your mainboard doesn't support mixed size modules (so anything other than 2x1GB, 2x2GB or 2x4GB), but this is highly unlikely in any mainboard made after 2010, so it should work without a problem. Page 16 of the Quick Specs seems to indicate that as well ("The below chart does not represent all possible memory configurations", which means that mixed memory should be fine). 2x4GB will definitely work, it's explicitly mentioned in the manual.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll start by adding one 4gb. I fit doesn't work I'll add the second one. regarding this Ram do you think it will work on my pc? https://www.amazon.it/dp/B009BRZHSS/?coliid=I2BEJNSN2FOA5M&colid=3M9UPSSPF9Z23&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it&th=1

Comment: It has the right specification, so yes, it will work. If it doesn't work initally, try removing the 2GB module to test only the 4GB one. Also you sometimes have to put the bigger module in slot 1 for it to work. If you encounter any problems, feel free to comment again and I'll try to help you.