# How to check compatible RAM

Tags: memory, ramdisk

I've bought a new laptop ASUS vivobook M415D.

I want to add more RAM into it. I can see there is an available slot in the board.

I want to know which specific RAM will be compatible with it.

User manual is not very clear since it has consolidated info for all related models & customer care is not much help either.

Below are the screenshots of task manager & cpu-z. Both shows different speeds, so I'm not sure which RAM to buy.

My guess is from task manager - 2400 will be compatible.

Right now it has only 4GB, I think additional 8GB will be good enough.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Comment: @Tetsujin, I've tried hwinfo and cpu-z. Let me try speccy. Issue is i'm confused by the different ram speed displayed by these tools.

Comment: Side note: If you're happy to spend a little more money, remove the old 4GB stick and get a matching pair of 8GB sticks. You'll get a speed boost as they will then operate in dual channel mode.

Comment: The entire idea of my dupe link is for those people who are confused by the raw info. If you don't know what you're doing, no amount of data is going to replace the comprehensive expertise you'll find in seconds from those online configurators.

Comment: @MiG, the existing RAM is non-removable.

Comment: Really? That's a new one for me, all my laptops had removable SODIMMS.

Comment: @MiG - many modern lappies have no replaceable RAM at all. The last MacBook made with user upgradeable RAM was released in 2012.

Comment: Not familiar with macs, but outside of the apple world it could also be a price range thing, come to think of it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Please, no “lappies.” Please, please, please…