# Finding the right RAM memory

Tags: laptop, memory

I've been for a while thinking on buying a few new hardware pieces for my old laptop.

The cheapest that would help is RAM. I run linux, so I typed `lshw -class memory` and got

```
 *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 24
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 4GiB
     *-bank
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: M471A5244CB0-CRC
...
```

Also `lshw -class system`, and got:

```
description: Notebook
    product: 80XS (LENOVO_MT_80XS_BU_idea_FM_ideapad 320-15ABR)
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: Lenovo ideapad 320-15ABR
```

So I am looking for an upgrade of ram in a Lenovo ideapad 320-15ABR. I searched [on the lenovo website](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/300-series/320-15abr/80xs/parts/display/compatible)

But weirdly enough my current RAM does not appear there. They are mostly 2400MHz as opposed to 1866 MHz.

That is the only requirement that keeps me in doubt before buying anything.

Do you know if this would be important? Can I just move to a 8GB/16GB 2400MHz?

Do you recommend any other clock frequency?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: A simple and fairly fullproof partial solutuin is to go to the kingston and/or crucial site and select your device from their memory configurator.  It will show memory specs and sizes which they guarantee will work.

Comment: Your current Samsung memory actually is [DDR4 2400](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/resources/data-sheet/M471A5244CB0-CRC00.pdf) by the way.  **Lenovo does not manufacture it's own memory.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use RAM with a higher **maximum** bus frequency, even if your CPU has a lower **maximum** RAM frequency, it will automatically select the appropriate frequency without your intervention.

To find your CPUs maximum RAM frequency you need to look up its specifications, for example [here you can find the specifications for the AMD model of your notebook](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/Lenovo_Laptops/ideapad_320_15_AMD/ideapad_320_15_AMD_Spec.PDF)

[more info](https://hardwaresecrets.com/understanding-ram-timings/)