# Can i use PC3L-12800E instead of PC3-12800U

Tags: memory, dell-optiplex

I have Dell Optiplex 7010 PC with 4g pc3-12800u installed RAM, I tried to install pc3l-12800e ram, but the pc not booting and power button blink 3 then 5 times. So what's the issue? And in general can i install pc3l-12800e RAM instead of pc3-12800u.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add ECC Low Voltage RAM to a machine designed to take standard voltage Unbuffered RAM.
This is unlikely to work.

L = Low voltage
E = ECC
U = Unbuffered

See [Wikipedia - DDR3 SDRAM/Variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#Variants) for more detail.

If you are uncertain as to what RAM you need, don't guess. Use an online RAM configurator. See [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer) for examples.