# RAM upgrade the RAM of my HP Slim PC from 8GB to 16 GB

Tags: memory

It currently has SK Hynix 8GB DDR4 RAM **(8GB 1Rx8 PC4-2666V-UA2-11)** module installed, can I install the different brand RAM module or should I use the same one as installed currently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Comment: The brand doesn't matter, but the specifications do.