# Can I safely use the same mhz server memory card on my Lenovo desktop?

Tags: desktop, ddr3, memory-card

I have a Lenovo tower. I was completely unaware that there is a difference between server memory and desktop memory when I purchased online. My question is can I safely use the same mhz (16g) cards I purchased?

Comment: There is as much difference as between desktop oriented or server oriented machine among themselves. Your question is unanswerable without hardware specifications, of the machine where you plan to use the modules and about the modules themselves. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: There is documentation for your system on the Lenovo site that will list the specific memory type(s) compatible with your computer. Only the supported types will work.

Answer (score 1):

Very probably not, but you'd need to tell us the exact spec of the RAM & also the motherboards of both computers. All other things being equal the biggest difference between 'server' & 'consumer' RAM is ECC support.

See [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Answer (score 0):

It ***might*** work. There will be no harm done if you try it out.

At worst, the system won't boot. So you'll have to remove the new RAM and re-install your old RAM.

At best, the ECC will be disabled.