# Is safe do an upgrade of RAM but without parity equality?

Tags: memory, upgrade, asus-laptop, hardware-detection

I have an *ASUS* `UX501VW-DS71T`, currently with 16GB of RAM.

According with the official documentation at [ASUS ZenBook Pro UX501VW](https://www.asus.com/us/commercial-laptops/asus-zenbook-pro-ux501vw/specifications/) about the RAM is indicated the following:

```
Memory
DDR4 2133 MHz SDRAM, up to 16 GB, OnBoard Memory 8 GB , 1x DIMM socket
```

Therefore is not possible do an upgrade to `2 x 16 = 32GB`. But *would be possible* do either `8 + 16 = 24GB` or `8 + 32 = 40GB`. **Note**: Lets assume is possible do an upgrade until 40 GB

Now, to be honest, since years ago I always have read and listened that is very important have a parity of RAM, I mean: `2 x R` such as `2 x 8`, `2 x 16`, `2 x 32`, etc. It for performance reasons *and* if my memory does not fail me to avoid the OS crash or hang (it mostly for `Windows` - not sure if `Linux` can be affected here too)

So far or in this point of time perhaps this situation was fixed due the current improvement of both hardware and software throughout these years.

**Question**

- Is safe do an upgrade of RAM but without parity equality?

Currently this laptop uses in peace Windows 10 Home, but in the future is considered to moved to Linux when Windows 10 passes to EOF. And well is used VirtualBox to use Linux as Guest

Of course, the **goal** is do an upgrade of RAM as maximum possible and have the OS and apps running in peace

Comment: There is no upgrade. It will take 16GB. You already have 16 GB. 8 onboard & 8 in the single available slot.

Comment: @Tetsujin: There are upgrades available for up to 40GB. See for example [CompuRAM](https://www.compuram.biz/memory/asus/notebook/zenbook/series/ux501vw/).

Comment: Interesting. I checked the usual suspects' configurators,  who agreed with 16 max

Comment: @Tetsujin when was released such laptop, in that point of time the max capacity was 16GB. Now consider that "perhaps" in that point of time did not exist a RAM stick of 16GB, so only 8GB: therefore only was possible to do either "2 x 8 or 8 + 8". Later when was available sticks of 16GB is possible do either 2 x 16 or 8 +16. Now the case could be that Asus did not updated its own documentation. It happens for other MacBook Pro too, for 2011 and 2012 were in their officials specs indicated the max capacity of RAM is 8, but really is 16GB

Comment: Sure. My own Mac was when released only capable of 64GB. After a firmware update, it can now take 128GB, or 96 in triple channel. Usually the Crucial/Kingston type configurators are ahead of the game on this. See [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Comment: Is it "safe"? Yes. Is it guaranteed to work? No.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the feedback and link - Even more to all: in the following [Asus ZenBook Pro UX501VW Notebook Review](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Asus-ZenBook-Pro-UX501VW-Notebook-Review.158762.0.html) link indicates: `Memory 23.9 GB, DDR4-2132, 1063.8 MHz, 15-15-15-36, Dual-Channel (8 GB integrated)` here appears `23.9GB` (I am assuming it is the max) and the `Dual-Channel` term appears **vs** [Zenbook UX501VW memory upgrades](https://www.compuram.biz/memory/asus/notebook/zenbook/series/ux501vw/) where appears 40GB as max but does not appear the `Dual-Channel` term

Comment: @Tetsujin pls, could you indicate me the model of your Mac? My sister has one of 2015/2016. I want to see if is possible do the same approach than yours. And perhaps do the same approach for the 2011/2012 to try to reach 32 - Who knows?

Comment: @Mokubai About `Is it guaranteed to work? No` - what would be the main reason to maybe receive problems? And that `No` what means? I mean, no startup? Hanging?

Comment: @ManuelJordan sticks of different types or timings *should* work at a common set of settings, usually the lowest common speed settings between them. A result is that combining 2400MT and 2600MT sticks might operate at 2400 speeds, or it could fall down to 2133MT/s. Or the memory controller might not find a common set of timings both modules accept. Either case might result in it not booting at all or having occasional or regular crashes or instability, or it might just be fine. I've had mixed sticks in the past and they worked well, but you get better speed and reliability when they match.

Comment: @Mokubai - thanks - Yes. I know is very important that both sticks have the same speed.  It if downgrade is applied or not to both sticks - well, it depends according the MOBO and CPU. Now, about _", but you get better speed and reliability when they match"_ Do you mean both with the same capacity? 2 x 8, right?

Comment: You can check for Mac models & RAM details on EveryMac's [Ultimate Mac Lookup](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/). Mine is an old Mac Pro, highly configurable. Modern Macs Are essentially non-upgradeable at all.

Answer (score 1):

Two identical RAM sticks are only required in order to enable
[dual channel](https://www.crucial.com/articles/about-memory/what-is-dual-channel-memory).

Dual channel memory is a technology that allows your CPU
to access two memory modules simultaneously, doubling the
bandwidth and speed of data transfer.

In your case, as you intend one stick to be much larger
than the other, dual channel is impossible.
If you could get your hands on an identical memory stick to the
existing one, dual channel might be possible with 16GB total,
although I must say that I haven't found any documentation
of whether this feature is supported by your motherboard.

Comment: I always think dual/triple channel can be a bit voodoo sometimes. It's fairly simple if you have but 2 slots. My own machine has 8 slots. It will dual if pairs match, no matter what the pairs are made of - but… it will triple channel if you put 6 identical cards in.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I also think that the chances for dual channel to really be effective are pretty low.

Comment: tbh, I've never really studied it. I stuck 8 identical 8GB cards in mine & called it a day. Works for me… as far as I can tell ;)

Comment: Its very unlikely that dual channel memory is going to be possible. When memory is partially on the motherboard and partially in a socket, the timings vary too much. Usually the reason for onboard memory + expansion is to have faster memory possible. It is closer to the processor than an expansion slot can be, and therefor also the timing is off. The expansion slot is used to accommodate for the need for more memory while not giving up the performance gain. It is silly to have 8GB onboard memory and an expansion slot if you are going to facilitate a dual channel memory setup.