# Can I upgrade 256x8 sodimm ram with 2Rx8 one?

Tags: memory, upgrade, ddr

My old laptop has only one slot for ram. Current ram is SODIMM DDR3 4GB 1333 256x8 CL9 (see attached picture). I want to upgrade ram to 8GB but did not find DDR3 8GB 1333 256x8 CL9. There are a lot of DDR3 8GB 1333 PC3-10600 2Rx8 CL9 in market, so my question is can use 2Rx8 instead of current ram which is 256x8?

P.S. There is no detail information about ram and ram upgrade in the laptop's official documentation.

[image]

Comment: without knowing the laptop make and model, there is no way to answer this question.  You can always *try* the memory.  Either it will work or it wont.

Comment: @Keltari laptop is Asus A54H. Yes it's easy to try but I have to deal with product return with market in case memory is not working

Comment: @John, in the RAM section of BIOS I don't see information about max RAM support. Can you tell how it looks or what exactly should I do to see it in bios? Laptop is Asus

Comment: See [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

The Crucial
[ASUS X54H RAM & SSD Upgrades](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/asus/x54h)
page has this upgrade:

---

[image]

---

I suggest to pay attention to the other parameters as above, to ensure
that your RAM is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

In short, answer is yes you can. There is no reason why you couldn't upgrade you ram rank(tho its possibly pointless).

Since your question isn't really clear, and goes into diagnostics;

- you will find your Laptop serial below it or below battery
- you need to check what that model motherboard max ram per slot is
- you also have to check your CPU stats on official page and decide on
  its support for max ram and max ram speed

Your things to "pay attention" at is, ram voltage and ram speed, in most cases(and your laptop doesn't have to be in it) if its same ram type(DDR3 for you), same speed (1333mhz) size will(read should, since XP ended its reign) load any other size.

And also you can Powershell(or try);

```
[math]::Round((Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray | ForEach-Object { $_.MaxCapacity }) / 1024 / 1024)
```